# Python selenium click on first HTML instance (SPAN) than contains specific/exact TEXT

Tags: python, selenium

In this Python code using Selenium and Firefox, I have a list of report names stashed in a file called New.txt.  The script cycles through these names, finds the name on the website, clicks (twice) and downloads the report.  The only issue is when the names of the reports are similar.  For example Jacks Report, Report, Report1, Report2, Mary Report.  When it gets to Report in the list, it errors out (throws an exception).  This makes sense because the code basically is finding three of the same report names.

I want to specifically alter the problem code below to find the exact report name.  When it searches for "REPORT" I want it to only identify that report and not REPORT1 and REPORT2.

Problem:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="' + z + '"]').click()
```

---

Whole code:

```
for x in range(0, i):      
while True:    
    try:

        x= x
        with open('C:/Users/me/Desktop/New.txt') as t:
            mylist = t.read().splitlines()
        z=mylist[x]
        print z

        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/ME/Documents/FirefoxProfile/')
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)

        browser.get('https://Websiteofdeath.com')
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").send_keys("USER")
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").send_keys("PASSWORD")
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_login").click()
        time.sleep(8)
        browser.get('https://Websiteofdeath.com')
        time.sleep(8)

        ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Foo')
        ProgramManagement.click()
        ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Foob').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
        time.sleep(8)           

        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="' + z + '"]').click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="' + z + '"]').click()
        #Click is mentioned here twice because I need to...click twice!                 
        #browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="' + z + '"]').click()

        time.sleep(30)
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_updateFilters_TitleAnchor").click()            
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass  
        time.sleep(30)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_ImageAnchor > img").click()
        time.sleep(30)

        path = 'C:/Users/ME/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS'
        count = len([g for g in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, g))])

        if count == x + 1:     # equal
            print "Made the speed"
            pass
        elif count != x + 2:   # not equal
            time.sleep(160)
            print "Waiting a little bit"
            pass
        browser.quit()
        os.rename('/Users/ME/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS/report.csv', '/Users/ME/Desktop/AUTOREPORTS/'+z+'.csv')
        print(count,"of",i)
    except:
        browser.quit()           
        continue
    else:
        break
```

This is the HTML code (snippet):

```html
</div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
        <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="/_layouts/ecm360/images/ReadReports.gif" alt="Key Plan Information" class="rtImg" /><span title="Key Plan Information" class="rtIn">Key Plan Information</span>
       </div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
        <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="/_layouts/ecm360/images/ReadReports.gif" alt="Key Plan Information with email addresses" class="rtImg" /><span title="Key Plan Information with email addresses" class="rtIn">Key Plan Information with email addresses</span>
       </div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
        <span class="rtSp"></span><img src="/_layouts/ecm360/images/ReadReports.gif" alt="Key Plan Information with email addresses and process description" class="rtImg" /><span title="Key Plan Information with email addresses and process description" class="rtIn">Key Plan Information with email addresses and process description</span>
       </div></li><li class="rtLI"><div class="rtMid">
```

Comment: The XPath you are using is identifying only exact matches.What is the error you are getting and when is it happening?

Comment: I have no idea how this happens. Your XPath should match the first span which contains a text node that equals to 'your-report-name'. Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: Depending on the type of error received we might need the html or not, please provide full stack-trace error if possible and the line where happens.

Comment: Updated original post to reflect HTML code that I am dealing with.  Notice that in my Python, the code is confused and throws an error due to it finding 3 of the "same" values.